# Get ordinal number of C++ variadic template parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, variadic-templates

I want to retrieve index of each parameter from `variadic template` parameters, currently I am using this approach:

From third party library:

```
struct statement {
  template <typename T>
  void bind(int, T t) { // ....
  }
};
```

My code:

```
template <unsigned Index, typename T>
void bind(statement& stmt, T t) {
    stmt.bind(Index, t);
}

template <unsigned Index, typename T, typename... Args>
void bind(statement& stmt, T t, Args... args) {
  bind<Index>(stmt, t);
  bind<Index + 1>(stmt,args...);
}
template <typename... Args>
void bind_all(statement& stmt, Args... args) {
  constexpr int Index = 0;
  bind<Index>(stmt, args...);
}
```

Usage:

```
statement stmt;
prepare(stmt, "insert into tab (a,b,c,d,e,f) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
bind_all(stmt, 1,1.24f, 3.14, "Hello", std::string{"World"}, true);
```

My question: Is there a better way to achieve this, to get ordinal numbers of `variadic template` parameters?

Edit:
I want to use this implementation to wrap `sql prepared statement` and to bind specific parameter to specific index.
Here is an example of code that I want to wrap, instead of listing each bind individually, I want to call `bind_all`

```
    prepare(stmt, "insert into tab (a, b) values (?, ?);");
    const int eight_int = 8;
    stmt.bind(0, &eight_int);
    const string eight_str = "eight";
    stmt.bind(1, eight_str.c_str());
    execute(stmt);
```

Comment: Kind of sounds like an XY problem.  Can you show what you'd like to acheive?

Comment: What if the same type appears twice in `bind_all`?

Comment: @NathanOliver, I just updated my question.

Comment: Seems like `std::tuple` may help here. Would allow also having the same type twice.

Comment: @AndyG, well, I will just use it to bind it at that specific index.

Comment: @ElvisOric: I see now. From your initial description it could have been that the same type should have always received the same index. Followup question: You basically want to automate `statement.bind(index+1, next_argument)` given some variadic parameter? I think that should be quite doable with a fold expression (or rather "simple expansion" since you don't have C++17)

Comment: @AndyG, sorry, I didn't initially describe it well. That's what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With simple expansion (could use a [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) in C++17)

```
struct statement
{
    template<class T>
    void bind(int index, T&& arg)
    {
       // magic
    }
};

template<class... Args>
void BindAll(statement& stmt, Args&&... args)
{
    using swallow = int[];
    int idx = 0;
    (void)swallow{0, (void (stmt.bind(idx++, std::forward<Args>(args))), 0)...};
}
```

I took some liberties with the API, but I think it maps close enough to your code.

Usage:

```
statement stmt;
BindAll(stmt, 1, 1.2, 1.3f, true, "abc");
```

#### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/aNgSM5eSpGhPRFv2)

Comment: With a little more boilerplate we could compute the indices at compile time, but this is simpler

Comment: Are all those `idx++`s guaranteed to be evaluated in the proper order pre-C++17?

Comment: @miles, the comma operator introduces a sequencing, so yes

Comment: @ElvisOric the answer and demo I've shown can run in c++11 or 14. Fold expressions, which I haven't used, are c++17

Comment: @AndyG, I was a little bit confused with `swallow` part. I see it now. :D

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a `std::tuple` for this.

```
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>

template<typename T, std::size_t... Index>
void doBind(Statement& st, T const& tuple, std::index_sequence<Index...> const&)
{
    // Using C++17 fold expression
    ((st.bind(Index, std::get<Index>(tuple))),...);
    // Using C++11 dummy variable
    int dummy[] = {0, (st.bind(Index, std::get<Index>(tuple)),0)...};
    (void)dummy; // to prevent unused variable warning.
}

template<typename... Args>
void prepare(std::string const& sql, Args&&... args)
{
    Statement statement;
    prepare(statement, sql);
    doBind(statement, std::make_tuple(args...), std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(args)>());
    execute(statement);
}
```

Comment: I am using third party library. That library provide `prepare` function with out param for statement. If I want to bind 6 parameters, I need to write 6 times `statement.bind(index, param)` and that part I want to automate. Also if I add another parameter in query, I need to shift all others by one. I just want to use it like  this: `bind_all(1,1.24f, 3.14, "Hello", std::string{"World"}, true);`

Comment: This solution is using c++17? I am getting "fold-expressions only available with '-std=c++17'"?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `std::index_sequence` to create a second template parameter pack containing the matching indices:

```
template <typename... Args, size_t... Is>
void bind_all_helper(std::index_sequence<Is...>, Args... args) {
    int dummy[]{(bind<Is>(args), 0)...};
    (void)dummy;  // just to avoid unused variable warnings
}

template <typename... Args>
void bind_all(Args... args) {
    bind_all_helper(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(args)>{}, args...);
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4c7a88dc843b72f0)

This uses a dummy array definition along with the comma operator to create a sequence of calls to `bind`.  For example, given `bind_all(1, 3.14)`, the array definition would expand to something like this:

```
int dummy[] {
    (bind<0>(1),    0),
    (bind<1>(3.14), 0)
};
```

Each element of the array ends up being `0`, but its evaluation has the side-effect of calling `bind<N>(arg)`.

---

With C++17 the `dummy` array definition could be replaced with a fold expression, but that obviously isn't an option if you're limited to C++14.

Comment: Use: `int dummy[]{0,(bind<Is>` for situations when `args` is empty.